# How to use \begin{cases} inside a table?

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[width=18.5cm, height=26cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}}
        
\hline \hline 
\bf{ssssssss} & \bf{sssssssssss} & \bf{ssssssssss}& \bf{sssssss}  \\ 
            
\midrule    
            
\multirow{1}{*}{equation}  & alooo & pyaaaaz& 
            \[
            %l=
            \begin{cases} 
                a &\text{when sth }\\
                b &\text{when sth else} \\
                c &\text{when elsewhere;}
            \end{cases}
            \] \\
            
\multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxx}&yyyyyyy&zzzzzz& 
            \[
            %l=
            \begin{cases} 
                a &\text{when sth }\\
                b &\text{when sth else} \\
                c &\text{when elsewhere;}
            \end{cases}
            \] \\
            
\multirow{1}{*}{xxxxxxx}& 
            \[
            %l=
            \begin{cases} 
                a &\text{when sth }\\
                b &\text{when sth else} \\
                c &\text{when elsewhere;}
            \end{cases}
            \]&yyyyyyy&zzzzzz \\
            
            
        \hline \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

For this, I am getting a table using \begin{cases}, but not a perfect table(attached here).

[image]

I want a perfect table with \begin{cases}  like table2(attached here).[image]

I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: note `\bf` has not been defined by default in latex for 30 years, if you do use article class's legacy definition note it does not take an argument, the syntax is `{\bf aaa}` not `\bf{aaa}`

Answer (score 4):

You can't use `\[...\]` in a table cell that's not declared as a `p` column. But you don't need it, which also needs to guess a width: just use simple inline math mode in an `l` column.

The `\multirow` declaration do nothing at all (or they possibly do harm). Also `\bf` has been deprecated for about 30 years and it has *never* taken an argument.

Avoid double rules and beware of spurious spaces.

Finally, I added a couple of `\addlinespace` to better separate those high rows.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
  width=18.5cm,
  height=26cm,
  heightrounded
]{geometry}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{} l l l l @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{ssssssss} & \textbf{sssssssssss} & \textbf{ssssssssss}& \textbf{sssssss}  \\ 
\midrule
equation  & alooo & pyaaaaz &
            $
            %l=
            \begin{cases} 
                a &\text{when sth}\\
                b &\text{when sth else} \\
                c &\text{when elsewhere;}
            \end{cases}
            $
\\ \addlinespace
xxxxxxx & yyyyyyy & zzzzzz &
            $
            %l=
            \begin{cases} 
                a &\text{when sth}\\
                b &\text{when sth else} \\
                c &\text{when elsewhere;}
            \end{cases}
            $
\\ \addlinespace
xxxxxxx &
            $
            %l=
            \begin{cases} 
                a &\text{when sth}\\
                b &\text{when sth else} \\
                c &\text{when elsewhere;}
            \end{cases}
            $
& yyyyyyy & zzzzzz
\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Please add a caption}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't need a caption, then you don't need `table` either: just place the `tabular` in a `center` environment if you want it in a fixed position (but it's better to let it float and to add a caption).

Answer (score 3):

You are using a displaymath environment `\[Displayed math\]` which centers the content in a line of its own. This is the spacing you see.

Replace those with inline math `$inline math$`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[width=18.5cm, height=26cm]{geometry}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm} p{4cm}}
        
\toprule \toprule 
\bf{ssssssss} & \bf{sssssssssss} & \bf{ssssssssss}& \bf{sssssss}  \\ 
            
\midrule    
            
equation  & alooo & pyaaaaz& 
            $
            %l=
            \begin{cases} 
                a &\text{when sth }\\
                b &\text{when sth else} \\
                c &\text{when elsewhere;}
            \end{cases}
            $ \\
            
xxxxxxx&yyyyyyy&zzzzzz& 
            $
            %l=
            \begin{cases} 
                a &\text{when sth }\\
                b &\text{when sth else} \\
                c &\text{when elsewhere;}
            \end{cases}
            $ \\
            
xxxxxxx& 
            $
            %l=
            \begin{cases} 
                a &\text{when sth }\\
                b &\text{when sth else} \\
                c &\text{when elsewhere;}
            \end{cases}
            $&yyyyyyy&zzzzzz \\
            
            
        \bottomrule \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I removed the `multirow` command since they didn't add anything to the table.